# Find closest BoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

I have an array of ClientRect objects which I got by doing

```
var trackedElements = $('[track]');
var trackedBounds = [];
_.each(trackedBounds, function(elem) {
    return $(elem)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
});
```

What I also have is another element's bounding client rect.

`var currentElement = $('.active')[0].getBoundingClientRect();`

My question is, how do I find within `trackedBounds`, the closest north of `currentElement`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filter rects that are not north of `currentElement`:

```
trackedBounds = trackedBounds.filter(rect => rect.bottom > currentElement.top)
```

and sort remaining rects on their `.bottom` property:

```
trackedBounds = trackedBounds.sort((rect1, rect2) => rect1.bottom - rect2.bottom)
```

Result is first element of `trackedBounds` array:

```
let result = trackedBounds
    .filter(rect => rect.bottom > currentElement.top)
    .sort((rect1, rect2) => rect1.bottom - rect2.bottom)
    [0]
```